# how  to get  the  value  of   json data  using python

Tags: python, json

this is my code :

```
a = '''{"title":"sss","body":"wwww：aaa&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  
<a href='#' onclick='logout()' >fff</a>  
","data":{"status":0,"userName":"www","userId":"433"}}'''
a = eval(a)
print a.title
```

but it show error :

so what can i do ,

thanks

Comment: Sorry, can't help.  Never seen this error before.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Noob: How to decode JSON with Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331943/noob-how-to-decode-json-with-python)

Comment: you've asked nearly 1000 questions here, you should know by now: you need to show the error you got.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use a JSON parser such as the `simplejson` module rather than using `eval`:

```
>>> a = '''{"title":"sss",
"body":"wwww：aaa&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='#' onclick='logout()' >fff</a>",
"data":{"status":0,"userName":"www","userId":"433"}}'''
>>> import simplejson
>>> parsed_data = simplejson.loads(a)
>>> parsed_data['title']
'sss'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would also try demjson. this should let you write your json data as a python object and then encode it.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine here. But you should be using `json`/`simplejson` to deserialize, not `eval()`.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are accessed as `a["title"]` in Python, not `a.title`.

Apart from this, you should use Python's `json` module instead of `eval()`.