# How to use tqdm for JSON file load progress bar?

Tags: python, json, tqdm

I'm writing a Python script for JSON file processing. It's basically divided in three procedures: load, encoding and printing. While I've easily created progress bars for encoding and printing using tqdm, I can't figure out how to do it for load.

I've thoroughly read tqdm docs and searched even here, but no clues

```
import json
from tqdm import tqdm, trange
from iso3166 import countries

geo_json_events_path = r'/cygdrive/c/elastic/gtd.geojson'

with open(geo_json_events_path) as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

I expect the progress bar for `json.load()` method shown.

Answer (score 4):

Got it!

Using the `object_hook` argument in `json.load()` method. I had already tried using this with a simple counting function that returned a value three times bigger than the number of lines in the source file, so I assumed it was wrong. After undertanding that my function was executed for each dictionary returned by `json.load` I realized that there are three dictionaries per line in my file so my function was OK, I just had to find the right nesting level in the json data to get the desired iteration. This is the outcome:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import json

def hook(obj):
    value = obj.get("features")
    if value:
    pbar = tqdm(value)
    for item in pbar:
        pass
        pbar.set_description("Loading")
    return obj

f = open('/cygdrive/c/elastic/gtd_tst.geojson')
docs = json.load(f, object_hook=hook)
for doc in docs:
    print(doc)
```

The first answer in this post was really helpful to find the solution : [Python decode nested JSON in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32388770/python-decode-nested-json-in-json)

Comment: Thanks man that's gold vor beginners

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly more general solution to this for importing json files that have multiple objects:

```
def hook(obj):
    for key, value in obj.items():
        pbar = tqdm(value)
        if type(value) is list:
            for _ in pbar:
                pbar.set_description("Loading " + str(key))
    return obj

f = open(r"C:\my_json_file.json")
my_json_file = json.load(f, object_hook=hook)
```

Although it still doesn't show the total progress if you have nested objects, just the progress of importing the current object.

Answer (score 0):

For my use case, I wanted to see progress not of a list but an object with lots of entries. Also I wanted to exclude a bunch of stuff because I was only interested in the top-level progress. This is an adaptation of Sean's answer:

```
def hook(obj):
    for key, value in obj.items():
        # don't care about these keys
        if key in ["mean_vector", "variance_vector", "variance_of_mean_vector", "variance_of_variance_vector"] or key[-4:] == ".jpg":
            continue
        
        if type(value) is dict:
            pbar = tqdm(value.keys())
            for _ in pbar:
                pbar.set_description("Loading " + str(key))
    return obj
```

Note that there is may still be a substantial delay between start of loading and appearance of progress bar, presumably because the file has to be read first (2GB json file in my case).